# How to add a border to an image on the left side in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, border

I pasted an image into my document in Word 2010. I'd like to add a border to the image to its left side.  I can't seem to find an option to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the image and select Format Picture... Choose Shadow from the left pane and activate the effect. Adjust the angle to 180 degrees, and the color that you want. Change the blur value to 0, and the transparency value to 0. At this point you will have a color bar on the left of your image. Use the distance value to adjust the size of the bar. Leave the size value alone.